# Query working in MYSQL but not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am executing the following commands in my model php in Codeigniter:

```
$sql=mysql_query("select name from reseller_domain where name='".$name."'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($numrows!=null || $numrows==0)
{
  return 'f';
}
else
{
 return 't';
}
```

I am not getting any result whatsoever. However, the same query is running perfectly fine in phpmyadmin.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: sidenote: dont use deprecated functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your DB setup in codeigniter, and where you were in phpmyadmin are using a different default schema.

Try it with: "select name from database_name.reseller_domain where name='".$name."'"

Comment: Nope, there is only one database that I am connecting to. It is working fine for all other queries. Even for this query, it worked yesterday. But today it suddenly stopped working. I am unable to figure out the issue. Anyway, I tried your suggestion. Still not result.

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for your advise. Your answer is not fully correct but it was very close. I had to use a 'tank_auth' prefix to the table name. And the issue was solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**1.** [mysql_* is deprecated so avoid using that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944958/1463622)...
**2.** Are you executing the [mysql_connect()](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect) command first?
**3.** [Your code is prone to sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

---

**4.** Since you are using codeIgniter, Im assuming you want to use the CodeIgniter framework to access your database

Have a look here on [how to use codeigniter to access your database](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html). In short:

1. [Configure CI by adding your database settings](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html)
2. Try this in CodeIgniter

   ```
    $sql = "select name from reseller_domain where name = ?";
    $this->db->query($sql, array($name));
    if($query->num_rows() == 0){
        return 'f';
    }else{
        return 't';
    }
   ```

Comment: @user3126593 Did you configure codeigniter with your database settings?

Comment: of course yes. This is the only that is not working for me. All others are working fine.

Comment: @user3126593 Can you tell us what errors you get? You can check using the way echo_Me said

Answer (score 1):

try that and see what error you got.

```
  $sql=mysql_query("select name from reseller_domain where name='".$name."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

edit:

why you check like that ?

try check like that:

```
   if($numrows==0)
    {
```

Comment: I want to check whether there are any rows returned or not. If number of rows returned is 0, then I want to return a false.

Comment: try that iff it works `select name from reseller_domain where name='Yourname'` give yourname with an exisitng name and see if it work.

Comment: even tht doesn't return a result.. I tried using an existing name from the table.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Seriously my man, you need to start using the CI DB class, this is not a good practice.
First of all, try getting your query in a var and exit it to the screen. Then see what the actual query gets and try this in your PHPMYADMIN. I suspect errors with the $name var.

===========================================================================

It looks like you didn't select a database.

Try using Code Igniters DB class?

If you don't already do,

```
$this->db->query('select name from reseller_domain where name='".$name."');
```

Must say though you'd better read the docs about it, it might help you a little further. If you did the query with the CI Db class you might want to see the actually outputted query with:

```
exit($this->db->last_query()); //yes exit isn't good, not even for debugging. But it works.
```

Then see what goes wrong inside of your query.

Comment: I tried the CI DB way too. Even that didn't return any result. :(

Comment: Then try to put your query in a var first. $query = 'SELECT etc' and then exit $query;. Look at the query and use it in PHPMYADMIN. What result you get?